# IIS has problems with some python modules (Plotly)

Tags: python, flask, iis

I have an python flask app which runs perfectly.
When i try to run this app in IIS, the app crashes with no log (only generic error 500) at this line:
fig = go.Figure()

go come from this import:
import plotly.graph_objs as go

Comment: The problem cannot be solved based on 500error alone, you can use failed request tracking to get detailed error information. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Answer (score 0):

I enabled the failed request tracking. Below is a screenshot of the summary.

[Summaray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9ciR.png)

Before the fastcgi error i got this:

```
GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_END BytesReceived="0", ErrorCode="Ende der Datei (EOF) erreicht.(0x80070026)"
```

Comment: maybe you should try installing VC++ runtime as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/a/613940).